# Tricky Java Strings Interview Q. Given List<String> and char [] return longest string containing only char []

Tags: java, string, algorithm, list, char

Given a List of Strings and an array of characters, return the longest String that contains only characters in the array.

I'm pretty sure I hosed it up. My first instinct was to use a regular expression but I don't think anybody gets those right the first time and without looking anything up.

Is there a tricky way of doing this using bitwise operators or something?

Comment: the easiest solution I can imagine is 2 nested loops

Comment: how large is the List of strings? And how long on average is each word? There's these and many other questions you can ask before you try to be clever and realize nothing's wrong with brute forcing it

Comment: I did use brute force, i.e. a double loop. It's a Q from one of the Ivy League .coms out here in the Seattle area so I'm thinking it's trickier than that.

Comment: Can the result string contain repeated characters from the char array?

Comment: I'd suggest either of the two: 1) convert `char[]` into set of chars which leads to O(n) solution; 2) sort `char[]` and use binary search which leads to O(n log m) solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code uses binary search on a sorted char array to efficiently check, if all characters of the string exist in the `char[]`. Note that binary search on an array is pretty fast due to cache locality.

```
public String longest(char[] chars, List<String> strings) {
    char[] sorted = Arrays.copyOf(chars, chars.length);
    Arrays.sort(sorted);
    String result = null;
    for (String string : strings) {
        if (containsAll(sorted, string)
            && (result == null || string.length() > result.length())) {
            result = string;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
public boolean containsAll(char[] sorted, String string) {
    int length = string.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        if (Arrays.binarySearch(sorted, string.charAt(i)) < 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This definitely looks more like what I think we are looking for.

Comment: There's an optimization to be had here to in that if char [] is longer than the String, skip it.

Comment: @user447607: That doesn't work if the `char[]` contains duplicates.

Comment: True. Unfortunately I didn't think to ask so I don't know if it does or not.

Comment: On second thought I think it actually does work, you are just not guaranteed which of the duplicates is selected... but this is irrelevant. If it's in there, it's in there.

Answer (score 3):

One idea would be to convert the `char[]` to a `Set<Character>` for O(1) containment tests, then simply loop over the list of strings and check if each particular string has only characters contained in the aforementioned set, keeping track of the longest string you find with this property.

If you have more information, you could make more optimizations. For example, if the strings themselves are very long but the list isn't, it might be beneficial to sort the list by length first, then start processing the strings longest first.

---

> Is there a tricky way of doing this using bitwise operators or something?

If you have some sort of (small-ish) limit on the range of character that can be included in the `char[]`, then you could potentially encode the whole thing in a single `int`/`long`, which would be a substitute for the `Set<Character>` I mentioned above. For example, let's say that only the characters from `'a'` to `'z'` will be included, then we can perform the encoding as follows:

```
long charset = 0;

for (char c : chars) {
    charset |= (1 << (c - 'a'));
}
```

Now, to check if some character `c` was contained in the original `char[]`, we can simply use:

```
if ((charset & (1 << (c - 'a'))) != 0) {
    // c was in the original char[]
}
```

Comment: Well this means copying at least N char's where N = the length of the char array. It also means instantiating N Char object wrappers so that they can be placed in a Collection. ...and that is before you consider the copying around during sorting. As for the bitwise operation, that seems a little TO tricky by comparison to the other solution. It's a neat idea though considering some other problems I've come across recently.

Comment: @user447607 Well your questions puts no limits on what N could be, so how can I factor that into my answer? Presumably N is not very large, in which case the pre-processing stage I describe should be very cheap and beneficial in terms of the time it saves you down the road. Regarding the second part of your comment, I think the `long` encoding is simpler than the `Set` solution in many ways (assuming your situation allows for it). I'm not sure how I could possibly tell if a solution is "tricky" (as you ask for) but not "too tricky".

Comment: Agree that the point is actually moot, since I didn't ask the question, "How large is 'N'?". However with the Seattle area Ivy League dot coms, one usually expects very large N's or perhaps many repetitious instances of the premise, i.e. small N's but millions of instances thereof. For example a million users, with 2-3 occurrences each. Either way, smaller memory footprint with fewer objects. Agree that finding a way to eliminate duplicates is wise in production but I don't think this was the main focus of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are allowed to use Java 8:

```
public static Optional<String> longestValidWord(List<String> words, char[] validCharacters){

  String allValidCharacters = new String(validCharacters);

  return words.stream()
    .filter(word -> word.chars().allMatch(c -> allValidCharacters.indexOf(c) > -1))
    .max((s1, s2) -> Integer.compare(s1.length(), s2.length()));
}
```

Comment: I've not had an opportunity to use Java 8 yet, so there's no way I could have come up with this.

Answer (score 0):

[arshajii's first solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24790557/tricky-java-strings-interview-q-given-liststring-and-char-return-longest-s#answer-24790686) implementation:

```
/**
 * @param  list List of Strings.
 * @param  array Array of characters.
 * @return The longest String from list that contains only characters in the array. 
 *         If there is no such String, "" will be returned.
 */
private static String getLongest(List<String> list, Character[] array) {
    String longest = "";
    if (list == null || list.isEmpty() || array == null
            || array.length == 0) {
        return longest;
    }
    Set<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList(array));
    for (String word : list) {
        boolean valid = true;
        for (Character c : word.toCharArray()) {
            if (!set.contains(c)) {
                valid = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (valid && longest.length() < word.length()) {
            longest = word;
        }
    }
    return longest;
}
```